# What's a good stack to post about office decoration

Tags: discussion

The company I work for recently moved to a new, much bigger office. This means we now have a rather big room where most of us sit and work in one half (there's also a kitchenette with a few coffee tables), but on the other side there is a 4x10m area with no furniture "yet" (except a couch), and nobody ever really goes there because there's no reason to. It's just a void.

What's a good use for such an area? What's a *fun* use for such an area? Ideally, it should be something that invites fun and positivity, but not something that distracts us when we're working.

I haven't asked about a "fun budget" so I guess low-cost ideas are preferable, or ones that can be "undone" relatively easily.

Comment: Unless there's a Home Decoration SE which specifically allowed subjective questions, this would be off-topic on the entire network as you're asking for opinions.

Comment: ...which was exactly my (sad) expectation, and why I posted on Meta. I'll find another watering hole for it. :)

Comment: You might try [chat] for this - it's a good place for these sorts of opinion questions, which are a better fit for discussion.

Comment: I don't see why this would be off-topic in The Workplace. Seems as on-topic as many questions like this: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/59295/how-can-we-promote-informal-water-cooler-moments-in-a-remote-only-organization or this: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3105/team-building-activities-for-a-fast-growing-team

Comment: "What's a good use for such an area? What's a fun use for such an area? " - couches, and a few tables+chairs for coffee, snacks, and quiet chats.

Comment: We do have couches (that nobody uses), and we do have coffe tables by the kitchenette.

Comment: [The fourth place: Polling, Recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57383/165773)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't think of any Stack Exchange site that this will fit into.  Not because there isn't necessarily a site for the topic, but because your question is primarily opinion based.